# Cut pasted text on limited textField length

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the code as follows :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if(range.length + range.location > textView.text.length)
    {
       return NO;
    }
    NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;
    return newLength <= 80;
}
```

To limit text edition up to 80 characters in my textField.

I'd like a way to past text in that textField but instead of it being denied to paste, just cut it so it fills the 80 characters.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the new string, truncate to 80, and update the text view.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *newText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString: text];
    if (newText.length > 80) {
        newText = [newText substringToIndex: 80];
        textView.text = newText;

        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the textView already has content? Or if the user only replaces a part of it?

Comment: This code deals with that. The first line in my answer takes the current value, does the replacement based on the current selection and the entered (typed, pasted, or removed) text, and then truncates that updated text to the first 80 characters.

Comment: The text gets updated but the position of the cursor is incorrect (before the replacement text)

Answer (score 0):

Here is **Swift** version with slightly different solution.

```
func textField(
        _ textField: UITextField,
        shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
        replacementString string: String
    ) -> Bool {

        let maxCharactersCount = 80

        guard
            let textFieldText = textField.text,
            let stringRange = Range(range, in: textFieldText)
        else {
            return false
        }

        let newTextFieldText = textFieldText
            .replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
            .prefix(maxCharactersCount)
        textField.text = String(newTextFieldText)
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Need answer in Obj-C insted of Swift

Comment: I know, but I still believe that Swift answer would be helpful. I found that thread jusst because I was looking for Swift solution and probably more people would do so. Especially that there is no similar post on this topic here on SO (there are plenty about limiting characters number but without cutting pasted text).